# Is there a faster method to do this sort of indexing in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy arrays a and b as below.

```
a.shape = (100,10000)
b.shape = (100,)
```

Need a c of shape (100,) such that,

```
for i in range(0,len(b)):
   c[i] = a[i,b[i]]
```

I want a faster way of doing the above. For loops can't be used in the scenario I'm using.. It works, but still expensive. Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: I'm sorry. The loop had a mistake earlier, I have now corrected it. Please see it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do:

```
import numpy as np

c = a[np.arange(len(b)), b]
```

That is about as fast as it gets. In the following code

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((1000000, 10))
b = np.random.randint(0,10,1000000)
c = a[np.arange(len(b)), b]
```

the last operation takes 31 ms (by IPython's `%timeit`), i.e. 31 ns per indexing.

Comment: I don't think you want `c[i]` on the left side of the assignment in your first code block, just `c`. The second block has it right.

Comment: @Blckknght: The Black Knight just sworded down one stupid error. Sorry for my carelessness, and thank you for pointing it out!